# git bash terminal in eclipse truncates text until eclipse window resize

Tags: eclipse, cygwin, git-bash

Using eclipse on windows, when I start a git bash terminal (or cygwin) and eclipse is maximized to fill the screen, the text in the terminal is cut off after 80 characters, as shown below...

[image]

If i then resize eclipse, the text eventually expands to fill the entire width of the terminal window...

[image]

Not sure if this is an eclipse issue or git bash/cygwin issue, but I don't have this issue when running git bash outside of eclipse.

This may be related to the version of eclipse I was using.  The issue was in eclipse 2021-06.  I've just installed 2022-03 (running with java 13) and this issue doesn't appear to be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was reported in [issue 514287 "Terminal cuts commands at 80 character"](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=514287).

However, issue like [573730 "Turn on ConPTY as default PTY in Windows"](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=573730) might have helped and resolved this, with terminal 10.6.0.